# On the edge of Scrapping and re-design, any help on VBA filling a formula accross to end of columns + Rows

Tags: excel, vba

Im on the last stage of a build and I have come to a stumbling block, if I cant resolve this its a whole new design

What I am trying to do is take the Active cell formula and fill across to the end of the columns, then fill down however the results its giving me is the same formula with the same data across all columns. The formula is not adjusting as it moves across the columns.

[results 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr0L1.jpg)

[Results should be - done manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujKLc.jpg)

Using module 1 this is run able but produces results in pic 1, but I need the results in 2

link to test data
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2vz1z7uap2u3dqnks02g5/test-Automated-clearing-report.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=fr9vifmheu50m01ab44rvlcil

my code which works (module 1)

```
Sub Macro4()
'


'
    Range("GRIR_Table[[#Headers],[Ageing Catagory]]").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="AP Researched by", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
     ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(ImportTable[[ Researched by]],MATCH(GRIR_Table[@[PO/PO Line]:[PO/PO Line]],ImportTable[[PO/PO Line]:[PO/PO Line]],0)),"""")"
 
 

 Range("AD2", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).FormulaR1C1 = Range("AD2").FormulaR1C1



 Dim GRrepLastColumn As Long, GRrepLastRow As Long
    GRrepLastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    GRrepLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, GRrepLastColumn)).FillRight
    Range(ActiveCell, Cells(GRrepLastRow, GRrepLastColumn)).FillDown
 
End Sub
```

any help to finish would be great

thanks

Dave

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `Range("AD2", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).FormulaR1C1 = Range("AD2").FormulaR1C1` ? What is `LastRow` and what is `LastCol`? What is stored in Range("AD2") and how does it relate to the macro?

Comment: To me, it looks like that line is either all you need, or is erroneous and is filling the sheet with unintended values.

Comment: When your formula uses Table Headers and Table Names, excel will not adjust them when you use `FillRight` and `FillDown`. If you want the formula to adjust automatically, you need to rewrite it using just worksheet addresses, not table names.

Comment: Share the screenshot loading them, not as a link it is more difficult to follow. Provide only relevant information to your problem. Please check the guideline for asking questions.